# Google DFP is rendering div for empty third party ad tags

Tags: google-dfp

I am using Google DFP Small Bussiness for ad serving and 
everything whas fine until I upgraded from GAM tags
to GPT tags.

The issue is as follows

1. I have a standard 300x250 Ad unit
2. I create a normal line items and add this ad unt to it
3. I upload third party ad code (from ad network). Sometimes this
   code will display the banner and sometime it wont.

Now with old GAM tags if third party ad is empty the GAM tag
will not render anything.

But with new GPT tag will render the div with 300px width and
250px height.

Is there any way to solve this issue.

Thx

Comment: Hey @nristic, any solution since? Mny thx

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the collapseEmptyDiv's method.

https://support.google.com/dfp_premium/answer/3072674?hl=en

Comment: Nop that is not it because as I mentioned. Sometimes that third party ad code will not return any banner but Google DFP will return third party ad code and It will render Div since it assumes that it will render something.